# How to add emission to a Unity water shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a water shader here(again). my other problem was solved  thanks to you. Now my water is not transparent anymore. because you guy have great knowledge and I hopped you can help me to add emission to the shader. It woulb be cool if the top of the waves have some Highlights. maybe its possible to use an emission map but just some emission would be very cool looking i think

i tried to this solotion but it didtn work for me

```
 _EmissionLM ("Emission (Lightmapper)", Float) = 0
 [Toggle] _DynamicEmissionLM ("Dynamic Emission (Lightmapper)", Int) = 0

 //Output
 o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_Illum, IN.uv_Illum).a;
```

This is the water shader

```
Shader "FX/Water" {
 Properties {
     _WaveScale ("Wave scale", Range (0.02,0.15)) = 0.063
     _ReflDistort ("Reflection distort", Range (0,1.5)) = 0.44
     _RefrDistort ("Refraction distort", Range (0,1.5)) = 0.40
     _RefrColor ("Refraction color", COLOR)  = ( .34, .85, .92, 1)
     [NoScaleOffset] _Fresnel ("Fresnel (A) ", 2D) = "gray" {}
     [NoScaleOffset] _BumpMap ("Normalmap ", 2D) = "bump" {}
     WaveSpeed ("Wave speed (map1 x,y; map2 x,y)", Vector) = (19,9,-16,-7)
     [NoScaleOffset] _ReflectiveColor ("Reflective color (RGB) fresnel (A)", 2D) = "" {}
     _HorizonColor ("Simple water horizon color", COLOR)  = ( .172, .463, .435, 1)
     [HideInInspector] _ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}
     [HideInInspector] _RefractionTex ("Internal Refraction", 2D) = "" {}

     //
     _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000)
     _EmissionMap("Emission", 2D) = "white" { }
     [Toggle] _DynamicEmissionLM("Dynamic Emission (Lightmapper)", Int) = 0
 }


 // -----------------------------------------------------------
 // Fragment program cards


 Subshader {
     Tags { "WaterMode"="Refractive" "RenderType"="Opaque" }
     Pass {
 CGPROGRAM
 #pragma vertex vert
 #pragma fragment frag
 #pragma multi_compile_fog
 #pragma multi_compile WATER_REFRACTIVE WATER_REFLECTIVE WATER_SIMPLE

 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 #define HAS_REFLECTION 1
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 #define HAS_REFRACTION 1
 #endif


 #include "UnityCG.cginc"

 uniform float4 _WaveScale4;
 uniform float4 _WaveOffset;

 #if HAS_REFLECTION
 uniform float _ReflDistort;
 #endif
 #if HAS_REFRACTION
 uniform float _RefrDistort;
 #endif

 struct appdata {
     float4 vertex : POSITION;
     float3 normal : NORMAL;
 };

 struct v2f {
     float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
     #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
         float4 ref : TEXCOORD0;
         float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD1;
         float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD2;
         float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;
     #else
        float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD0;
         float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD1;
         float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD2;
     #endif
     UNITY_FOG_COORDS(4)
 };

 v2f vert(appdata v)
 {
     v2f o;
     o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);


     // scroll bump waves
     float4 temp;
     float4 wpos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
     //temp.xyzw = wpos.xzxz * _WaveScale4 + _WaveOffset;
     temp.xyzw = wpos.yzyz * _WaveScale4 + _WaveOffset;
     o.bumpuv0 = temp.xy;
     o.bumpuv1 = temp.wz;

     // object space view direction (will normalize per pixel)
     o.viewDir.xzy = WorldSpaceViewDir(v.vertex);

     #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
     o.ref = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.pos);
     #endif

     UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
     return o;
 }

 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 sampler2D _ReflectionTex;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_SIMPLE)
 sampler2D _ReflectiveColor;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 sampler2D _Fresnel;
 sampler2D _RefractionTex;
 uniform float4 _RefrColor;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_SIMPLE)
 uniform float4 _HorizonColor;
 #endif
 sampler2D _BumpMap;

 half4 frag( v2f i ) : SV_Target
 {
     i.viewDir = normalize(i.viewDir);

     // combine two scrolling bumpmaps into one
     half3 bump1 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv0 )).rgb;
     half3 bump2 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv1 )).rgb;
     half3 bump = (bump1 + bump2) * 0.5;

     // fresnel factor
     half fresnelFac = dot( i.viewDir, bump );

     // perturb reflection/refraction UVs by bumpmap, and lookup colors

     #if HAS_REFLECTION
     float4 uv1 = i.ref; uv1.xy += bump * _ReflDistort;
     half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );
     #endif
     #if HAS_REFRACTION
     float4 uv2 = i.ref; uv2.xy -= bump * _RefrDistort;
     half4 refr = tex2Dproj( _RefractionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv2) ) * _RefrColor;
     #endif

     // final color is between refracted and reflected based on fresnel
     half4 color;

 #if defined(WATER_REFRACTIVE)
     half fresnel = UNITY_SAMPLE_1CHANNEL( _Fresnel,         
      float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color = lerp( refr, refl, fresnel );
     #endif

     #if defined(WATER_REFLECTIVE)
     half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, refl.rgb, water.a );
     color.a = refl.a * water.a;
     #endif

     #if defined(WATER_SIMPLE)
     half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, _HorizonColor.rgb, water.a );
     color.a = _HorizonColor.a;
     #endif

     UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, color);

     //o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_Illum, IN.uv_Illum).a;


     return color;
 }
 ENDCG

     }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself, but it seems that you can add a "meta" pass and add emission that way. Source: [Unity forums user tsangwailam](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-write-emission-to-lightmap-in-vert-frag-shader.462926/#post-3008402)

> ```
> Pass
> {
>     Name "META"
>     Tags {"LightMode"="Meta"}
>     Cull Off
>     CGPROGRAM
>
>     #include "UnityStandardMeta.cginc"
>     #pragma vertex vert_meta
>     #pragma fragment frag_meta_custom
>
>     fixed4 frag_meta_custom (v2f i) : SV_Target
>     {
>         // Colors              
>         fixed4 col = fixed(1,0,0); // The emission color
>
>         // Calculate emission
>         UnityMetaInput metaIN;
>           UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(UnityMetaInput, metaIN);
>           metaIN.Albedo = col.rgb;
>           metaIN.Emission = col.rgb;
>           return UnityMetaFragment(metaIN);
>
>         return col;
>     }
>
>     ENDCG
> }
> ```

Hope this helps!